# how to limit foreign key choices in the form page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

below are my models, I want to display only those groups in post form in which the user is joined in.
Example: if I joined in "mcu" group then only that group should be displayed, how should I do that??
[image]

GROUP MODEL

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='GroupMember')


class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_groups',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('group', 'user')
```

POST MODEL

```
User = get_user_model()

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='')
    message = RichTextField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        unique_together = ['user', 'message']
```

In views.py

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Post
    form_class = forms.PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('title', 'message', 'group')
        widgets = {
            'message': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3'}),
            'group': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: Please add the view and form class you have to the question.

Comment: Please add the forms.py file in the question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, @F A, i have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

If would've been good if you would've published the `views.py` of the above form and `forms.py` where the form is created.

Without seeing the above two files, you would need to perform something like the following.

In your forms.py file, you would have a similar form as below. You need to add `def __init__` to add the logic.

Example of the forms.py file-

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'message', 'group']

    def __init__(self, bundle_seller, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['group'].queryset = Group.objects.all().filter(members=loggedin_user)
```

The reference `loggedin_user` that you have referred in the last line above needs to be referred in the `views.py` file for Posts. I'm assuming you're using function-based view in the below example-

```
def new_post(request):
    ....
    loggedin_user = request.user
    form = PostForm(data=request.POST or None, loggedin_user=loggedin_user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ....
    else:
        form = PostForm(loggedin_user=loggedin_user)
```

Let me know in comments if the above helps.

Comment: I've updated the question please check the question once again

Comment: What is "bundle_seller" in __init__  function of forms.py and
What is ```self.fields['group'].queryset``` in forms.py